# how to solve git commit error when using it in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

[vscode commit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZWfe.png)

As shown in the above figure, in vscode we can use the commit button to submit a commit to the git repository.

However, I ran into a question when using the commit button. when I click the button, it shows the following error:

> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet
> Error: Bad status code: 500
> at ClientRequest. (/root/.vscode-server/bin/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/extensions/git/dist/git-editor-main.js:1:470)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:28)
> at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:618:27)
> at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
> at Socket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:482:22)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
> at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
> at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
> **error: There was a problem with the editor '"/root/.vscode-server/bin/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/extensions/git/dist/git-editor.sh"'.**
> Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

I don't know how to solve this, anyone can help? any information is appreciated.

Comment: Have you adding a commit message? What happens if you use the terminal and type `git commit -m "This is a commit message"`

Comment: What's the output of `git config core.editor`?

Comment: @Andersnk if use "git commit -m 'commit message'", it can work correctly

Comment: @KamenMinkov the output is nothing

Comment: This looks like an installation error with VSCode. It's not a Git issue, Git does not include `.vscode-server/bin/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/extensions`.